# SQL result convert into integer

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble convert this `String` `sql` results into int. Can you guys tell how to accomplish this.
I'm doing this because I need this value set in to a `JLabel` that shows attendance count.
I've tried to search for the answer here, but I couldn't find it. Please can you guys help me with this problem?

```
public static int attendanceCount() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String sql = "select count(accountNo) from attendance";
        Connection conn = DBConnection.getDBConnection().getConnection();
        Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rst = stm.executeQuery(sql);
        return rst; // How do I convert this into integer?
    }
```

This is what I need to accomplish.

```
private void setAttendanceTile() {
        try {
            int attendanceCount = AttendanceController.attendanceCount();
            inHouseMembersLabel.setText(Integer.toString(attendanceCount));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Or is there another way to accomplish this without doing this way?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the reason for down-vote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get ResultSet.getInt(1):

```
int id = rst.getInt(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ResultSet.getInt()` method. It takes either a [column index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int)) or a [column name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(java.lang.String)). [Here's an example from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html).

In your case you would need the one which takes the index (note that index starts with 1, not 0).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested earlier, try using `.getInt()` method.
Moreover, I would use `PreparedStatement`. It's important to use `PreparedStatement`, because it allows database to cache your queries.
Also, always close your `Connection` and `ResultSet` after using them.

```
public static int attendanceCount() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException  {
    final int COLUMN_NO = 1;
    final String SQL = "select count(accountNo) from attendance";
    Connection conn = DBConnection.getDBConnection().getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
    ResultSet rst = stm.executeQuery();
    int result = rst.getInt(COLUMN_NO);
    try {
        rst.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {} //ignore
    return result;
}
```